# How to convert this C++ for loop to Python?

Tags: python

Here is a for loop in C++. How would you convert this to Python?

```cpp
for(j=1, k=x; j<=x; j++, k--)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
j = 1
k = x
while j <= x:
   j = j + 1
   k = k - 1
```

Comment: If this solved your problem, please select this as the correct answer and mark this solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
j = 1
k = x
while j <= x:
   j += 1
   k -= 1
```

same as previous small changed

Answer (score 0):

I just think so:

```
x = 5
k = x
for j in range(1, x+1, 1):
    # do something
    print(j, k)
    
    k -= 1
```

And it output:

```
(1, 5)
(2, 4)
(3, 3)
(4, 2)
(5, 1)
```